# Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of AT TIME ZONE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I am pulling data from one table [SourceTable] where the datatype of the field that I am referencing (source) is VARCHAR. The [TargetTable] that I am trying to pull the data into has a data type of DATETIME.

I get the following error message when running the script:

[image]

Below is the script that I run:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET([BeginDateTime], DATEPART(TZOFFSET, [BeginDateTime] AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time'))) AS [BeginTime]
FROM [SourceTable]
```

Note: I have two instances, where the first is my 'raw' instance. From here, I do my modelling and conversions that is required to structure the data.

Comment: The message seems quite clear.  If you provided sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to implement, someone could answer *that* question.

Comment: ...and what is the datatype of your `[BeginDateTime]` column?

Comment: The *real* question is why do you have a column called `BeginDateTime` when it isn't a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15)? If it's a `varchar` it is, by definition, *not* a datetime.

Comment: Hi. Apologies, I am still developing my SQL skills. I have two instances, where the first is my 'raw' instance. From here, I do my modelling and conversions.

Comment: @CaiusJard [BeginDateTime] is a varchar

Comment: *"[BeginDateTime] is a varchar"* and there is your problem, @sqlenthusiast . The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. The first parameter, for `SWITCHOFFSET`, *needs* to be a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15). Fix your design, fix the problem; change the data type of your column `BeginDateTime` to an appropriate date and time value; seems like `datetimeoffset` is what you need.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your feedback. I think that is what I needed to know - that SWITCHOFFSET needs to be in a datetime related data type and that converting it would not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am facepalming myself because I initially rushed the solution. After looking at the script, I managed to resolve my issue by doing the following:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIME, [BeginDateTime], 120) , DATEPART(TZOFFSET, CONVERT(DATETIME, [BeginDateTime], 120) AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time'))) AS [BeginDateTime]
```

Comment: This is not really a solution. The correct solution is to use the correct datatype.

Comment: "Making an error message go away" and "resolving a fundamental problem with data modelling" are two very different things

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have a 'raw' instance where I treat everything as one data type. From here I perform the required transformations and modelling to move the data into a 'structured' instance. Based on the context, this would serve as a solution for my issue :)

Comment: That's a reasonable approach. You may wish to use `TRY_CONVERT` so that you can elegantly capture any formatting issues

Comment: Converting the data that includes the time zone offset to a datetime data type is not correct.  You should be using the datetimeoffset data type - which would simplify the process.  You wouldn't need to convert at all, just make sure the string is in the right format (ex: '2021-05-18 14:39:05.1790734 -04:00').